# $content: reworded about manipulating this variable

Tags: 6, theming

I see that this:

```
<body>
  <div id="content-area">
    <?php print $content; ?>
  </div>
  <?php print $page_closure; ?>
  <?php print $closure; ?>
</body>
```

Will actually render all the content of a page. So all those other variables are only for regions. But, remove that one variable, `$content` and no matter how much else PHP one has in the template, nothing gets rendered.

I'm trying to specifically call the primary and secondary links in certain areas of a `page.tpl.php` template.

My attempts moving around a code block within the standard `page.tpl.php` file haven't worked; wherever I put the secondary, they always appear below the primary.

For instance, this:

```
<?php 
   print theme(array('links__system_main_menu', 'links'), $primary_links,
   array(
      'id' => 'main-menu',
      'class' => 'links clearfix',
       ));
?>
```

Doesn't matter if it's after the secondary in source order... it always appear on top of my secondary links. Even if I put it below the $footer variable. So how can I get those links to be called in a different area of the page.tpl.php template?

I have no blocks in any region. I realize I can just use CSS to reposition the menus, but that doesn't seem right to move them across/down a page that kind of distance.

What is snippet/way to pull out specific content from the $content variable, specifically the primary and secondary links and place them within the page.tpl.php template where I would like them?

Comment: Given that you are commenting out the printing of the variable `$content_top` yet asking about the `$content` variable I am not really sure what your question is...

Comment: Sorry, I was trying to show that I've experimented and done more than just post. See the 2nd example where I took out all but the $content variable. My question is how do I set the actual document flow order of the information contained within $content? Since the ONE variable of $content prints EVERYTHING, I'd like to know how I re-order the $primary_links to appear anywhere within that variable instead of where it does by default.